# How to fill boxes of the pgfplots box plots with predefined colors?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pdftex, boxplot

How can I fill each pgfplots box with different predefined colors? The code below from https://www.latex4technics.com/?note=7WU2A1.

```
    \documentclass{minimal}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepackage{filecontents}

    \begin{filecontents}{testdata.dat}
     0 1 1.2 0.4 1.5 0.2
     1 2 2.3 1.5 2.7 1
     2 0.7 1.4 0.5 1.9 0.1
     3 1 1.2 0.4 1.5 0.2
     4 2 2.3 1.5 2.7 1
     5 0.7 1.4 0.5 1.9 0.1
    \end{filecontents}
    

    \pgfplotsset{
     box plot width/.initial=1em,
     box plot/.style={
        /pgfplots/.cd,
        black,
        only marks,
        mark=-,
        mark size=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/box plot width},
        /pgfplots/error bars/.cd,
        y dir=plus,
        y explicit,
     },
     box plot box/.style={
        /pgfplots/error bars/draw error bar/.code 2 args={%
            \draw  ##1 -- ++(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/box plot width},0pt) |- ##2 -- ++(-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/box plot width},0pt) |- ##1 -- cycle;
        },
        /pgfplots/table/.cd,
        y index=2,
        y error expr={\thisrowno{3}-\thisrowno{2}},
        /pgfplots/box plot
     },
     box plot top whisker/.style={
        /pgfplots/error bars/draw error bar/.code 2 args={%
            \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/error bars/error mark}%
            {\pgfplotserrorbarsmark}%
            \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/error bars/error mark options}%
            {\pgfplotserrorbarsmarkopts}%
            \path ##1 -- ##2;
        },
        /pgfplots/table/.cd,
        y index=4,
        y error expr={\thisrowno{2}-\thisrowno{4}},
        /pgfplots/box plot
     },
     box plot bottom whisker/.style={
        /pgfplots/error bars/draw error bar/.code 2 args={%
            \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/error bars/error mark}%
            {\pgfplotserrorbarsmark}%
            \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/error bars/error mark options}%
            {\pgfplotserrorbarsmarkopts}%
            \path ##1 -- ##2;
        },
        /pgfplots/table/.cd,
        y index=5,
        y error expr={\thisrowno{3}-\thisrowno{5}},
        /pgfplots/box plot
     },
     box plot median/.style={
        /pgfplots/box plot
     }
    }

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis} [enlarge x limits=0.5,xtick=data, box plot width=0.5em]
     \addplot [box plot median] table {testdata.dat};
     \addplot [box plot box] table {testdata.dat};
     \addplot [box plot top whisker] table {testdata.dat};
     \addplot [box plot bottom whisker] table {testdata.dat};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The code seems complicated considering the output.  You should provide some context. Questions: 1) I don't really understand the connection between the data and the six boxes (apart from the fact that there are six rows numbered from 0 to 5).  2) Do you want to color each box completely, or only the top or bottom part? 3) Is there a connection between the color of each box and the data on the corresponding row? 4) Finally, why do you use `filecontents`?

Comment: Moreover, the rows are two by two identical (with corresponding identical boxes).  Is this desired or only an accident?

Comment: @DanielN I needed to visualize many scientific experiment results with box & whisker plots but I only had basic LaTex knowledge but pgfplots . So I tried to find a LaTex template to create plots quickly and I ran into that code. I didn't write it. I thought maybe I could adapt the code for my situation however it was challenging than I expected. 1) The first column of the data indicates index, second column median, third and fourth column, box plot limits and remaining whiskers.  2) Yes, each box completely with different colors. 3) Yes, there is. Each data row has specific color code.

Comment: 4) It was only for example. 5) Again, it is an example. I did it on purpose.

Comment: OK!  The LaTeX/TikZ solution for the drawings is doable.  There is a remaining question from my point of view: How do you recuperate the data to perform the drawings?  Will the data be in an another file?  Will the data be written down in the drawing's file?  Then you say that the colour code of each row will be there...  Explicitly, or will it be inferred from the data?

Comment: Thanks for help. :) I will put data into .dat files with Python and load them from those files. I will use Hexadecimal color code and the colors will be same for each plots. So it is a repetitive task. I only need the create the LaTex code to draw plots. Then I will call same code again and again with different .dat files.

Comment: The data that I will print into .dat files will be like in the example. Each .dat file will contain 6 rows for 6 box&whisker plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The solution (i.e. the drawing) is based on a `pic` element `boxWW` which takes 7 arguments; the six numbers of a row and the colour.

The data is read from an exterior file through a `\csvreader` command.  So, as it is, the solution needs the package `csvimple`.  Of course, if the data is provided differently, the code should change accordingly.

With the command `filecontents` a data file is constructed to obtain an example (almost the one appearing in the question).

I couldn't figure out how the colours will be provided either; so I improvised with a function based on the numbers from each row.  It is not very interesting, but it is based on the `rgb` code; you could change it easily if need be.

**The code**

```
\documentclass[10pt, margin=17pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math, calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{zBoxes.dat}
 0, 1, 1.2, 0.4, 1.5, 0.2
 1, 2, 2.3, 1.5, 2.7, 1
 2, 0.7, 1.4, 0.5, 1.9, 0.1
 3, 1, 1.4, 0.4, 1.6, 0.2
 4, 2, 2.3, 1.5, 2.7, 1
 5, 0.7, 1.4, 0.5, 1.9, 0.1
\end{filecontents}

\tikzset{%
  pics/boxWW/.style n args={7}{% ... / color
    code={%
      \path (0, #2) coordinate (M);
      \path (0, #3) coordinate (T);
      \path (0, #4) coordinate (B);
      \draw[fill=#7] ($(B) +(-1ex, 0)$) rectangle ($(T) +(1ex, 0)$);
      \draw (M) ++(-1ex, 0) -- ++(2ex, 0);
      \draw (T) -- (0, #5) ++(-1ex, 0) -- ++(2ex, 0);
      \draw (B) -- (0, #6) ++(-1ex, 0) -- ++(2ex, 0);
    }
  }
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=0}]
  % the axes
  \draw (-1.1, 0) -- (6, 0);
  \draw (-1, 0) -- ++(0, 3);
  \foreach \i in {-1, ..., 5}{%
    \draw[very thin] (\i, 0) -- ++(0, -3pt) node[pos=1.7, below] {\i};
  }
  \foreach \j in {0, 1, 2}{%
    \draw[very thin] (-1, \j) ++(6pt, 0) -- ++(-8pt, 0) node[pos=1.3, left] {\j};
  }

  % boxes with whiskers
  \csvreader[no head]{zBoxes.dat}{%
    1=\bno, 2=\bmed, 3=\bmax, 4=\bmin, 5=\bwmax, 6=\bwmin}
  {%
    \tikzmath{% color constants
      real \tmpr, \tmpg, \tmpb;
      \tmpb = \bwmin/\bwmax;
      \tmpg = \bmin/\bwmax;
      \tmpr = \bmax/\bwmax;
    }
    \xdefinecolor{tmp}{rgb}{\tmpr,\tmpg,\tmpb}
    \draw (\bno, 0) pic {boxWW={\bno}{\bmed}{\bmax}{\bmin}{\bwmax}{\bwmin}{tmp}};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks Daniel! :)